# VBA sql query problem

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

Below query is resulting NO rows

```
lstResults.RowSource = "select EmpId from tblTesting where Empid ='" & Me.txtSearchEmpId.Value & "'"
```

Where below working fine :

```
lstResults.RowSource = "select * from tblTesting"
```

WHere is the fault here?
I check the value of '" & Me.txtSearchEmpId.Value & "'" using break point its having the value of "123" (numerical)

My empid is numerical value

Please help

Comment: Please take some time to learn a bit about SQL. Does the table have row(s) for EmpID = 123? What data type is the EmpID field? If it is a text field, do a TRIM on txtSearchEmpID

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your `EmpId` is numerical, you probably want to remove the single-quotes:

```
lstResults.RowSource = "select EmpId from tblTesting where Empid = " & Me.txtSearchEmpId.Value
```

How does that work?

Answer (score 1):

First, remove the single quotes from around your value, if it really is a number.

Second, *cleanse your input*. What if someone types `123 or true` into your input field? You've then let them select all inputs. You might want to convert the value to an integer and then back to a string to make sure it is pure.

See [xkcd #327](http://xkcd.com/327/):
[image: xkcd #327]

Comment: Exactly what could happen if they don't do that? Remember, the context is Access, and SQL injection risks are severely limited in Access as compared to other programming environments because of the fact that Access/Jet can't executed batched SQL statements.

Comment: @David W. Fenton: In the txtSearchEmpId.Value you could type x' = 'x and your assumption that the resultset will contain 1 or zero rows is blow out of the water e.g. could reveal information you were trying to restrict. Hard to be specific for a SQL statement targeting a table named tblTesting ;)